# Meteor simple todos what is the deference between server/main.js and client/main.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Meteor simple-todos tutorial (react version) is not working. There is already a startup script section on `server/main.js` but in the tutorial they are instructing to put that startup block on `client/main.js`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Files in the `server` folder are run only on the server and files in the `client` folder are only run on the client.

If the tutorial is telling you to modify the `client/main.js` file, they do indeed mean to only edit the `client/main.js` file.

`Meteor.startup` just tells meteor to run this bit after all Meteor code is ready, which is immediately after the server starts on the server, and after the page has loaded on the client.